# How to removeItems from localstorage that end with a particular number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

This should not be a hard task, but I am having some issues. I have a code that removes items from localstorage when clicked, but it is not working as expected. When there is only one occurrence of this code it works. However the code will need to be used in multiple occurrences (one for each div). When all the individual code blocks are added for each div, all localstorage items get removed simultaneously (04, 05, 06, 07, ...). It does not remove the targeted localstorage item from the div where the click originated. 
   All the items that need to be removed end in a number such as "state08, city08, country08, city09, state10, city10", and so on. I understand that localstorage only stores strings so I believe this to be the root of the problem. So with that being said, I am trying to get my code to work with the numbers that occur at the ends of each string. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

```
      $('.clear_button').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
        var num = 05;
        var n = num.toString();
        Object.keys(localStorage)
        .filter(key => key.endsWith(n))
        .forEach(key => localStorage
        .removeItem((key)))
    });
});
      $('.clear_button').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
        var num = 06;
        var n = num.toString();
        Object.keys(localStorage)
        .filter(key => key.endsWith(n))
        .forEach(key => localStorage
        .removeItem((key)))
    });
});


  <fieldset id="fieldset18">                                                                
  <label >Country</label>
   <select id="country18" class="country" name="country"> 
       <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <label State;</label>
    <select id="state18" class="state" name="state">
       <option value="" selected="selected">State</option>
    </select>                                                            
     <label >City</label>
     <select id="city18" class="city" name="city">
       <option value="" selected="selected">City</option>                                                               
      </select>                                                                
    </fieldset>
    <div>
    <p class="clear_button">clear</p>
     </div>
```

Here I am trying to convert 05 into a string then delete all strings that end in "05", but it does not work because the code that has "06" will also fire and delete all the "06" localstorage items as well. I need this code to work independently for each number so the user can clear the given localstorage items and not disturb others. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `key.endsWith("n")` should be `key.endsWith(n)`. Right now you are checking if the `key` ends with the letter `'n'`.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier , thanks for the response and catching that. I changed it however it still does not function as intended.

Comment: Could you format your code a little more and give an example with, say, three divs with their structure?

Comment: @Jazzpaths Web Staff, thanks. I added the markup. Each one looks the same other than the id numbers. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I read and see, when a user click a .clear_button class all the functions binded will be executed, so if you having n = 1...5 you'll have 5 click handlers for .clear_button and each one will remove the relative item from the localStorage, the item wich ends with 1, with 2, with 3, ..., with 5. That's why you got anything removed. But still is not clear to me the global picture and what you're trying to achieve.

You could store a number in the data attribute of each .clear_button and use that to clear, this way you'll only need of one handler (vs n handlers):

```
<a class=".clear_button" data-num="1">Remove 1</a>
<a class=".clear_button" data-num="2">Remove 2</a>
... etc ...
<a class=".clear_button" data-num="n">Remove n</a>

$( '.clear_button' ).click(function(){
  var n = $( this ).data( 'num' );
  Object.keys(localStorage)
    .filter(key => key.endsWith(n))
    .forEach(key => localStorage
    .removeItem((key)))
});
```

**Edit after your reply in the comments**

```
<fieldset id="fieldset18">

  <label>Country</label>
  <select id="country18" class="country" name="country"> 
    <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?>
  </select>

  <label>State</label>
  <select id="state18" class="state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected">State</option>
  </select>

  <label>City</label>
  <select id="city18" class="city" name="city">
    <option value="" selected="selected">City</option>                                                               
  </select>

</fieldset>

<div><p class="clear_button" data-num="18">clear</p></div>
```

Furthermore, if the localStorage items have fixed names and just different ending numbers, the jQuery code could be also reduced to this:

```
$( '.clear_button' ).click(function(){
  var n = $( this ).data( 'num' );
  localStorage.removeItem( 'city' + n );
  localStorage.removeItem( 'state' + n ); 
  localStorage.removeItem( 'country' + n );
  ...
});
```

Note I didn't used the zero padding for the numbers, in case you would have to add, but I would leave item names just like city1, city2, ... etc, without the zeros (city01, city02, ...).

Comment: Woohoo! You brought my week of frustration to an end. Thanks @Jazzpaths. You are great.